# How do I change Page Heading Based on URL Query Parameter

Tags: jquery

So, I am trying to use jQuery to change a heading tag on my page depending on the query parameter that is passed in the URL.

Possible URL parameters could be as follows:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com?type=friends
http://example.com?type=honeymoon
http://example.com?type=family
```

The following are the heading tags I'll be hiding and showing based on query passed.

```
<h2 id="default">Bali Vacations</h2>
<h2 id="friends">Friends</h2>
<h2 id="honeymoon">Honeymoon</h2>
<h2 id="family">Family</h2>
```

I would like to show only the `<h2 id="default"></h2>` when the user visits only the domain or goes to any other query parameter apart from the ones mentioned above.

Would appreciate it a lot if you guys can help me out. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Have been able to figure out how to do this. Is this the most ideal solution though?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // If no URL Query Param
        if(location.search == ""){
          $('.default_name').show();
        }
        // If honeymoon is query param
        else if(location.search == "?type=honeymoon"){
          $('#honeymoon').show();
        }
        // If family is query param
        else if(location.search == "?type=family"){
          $('#family').show();
        }
        // If friends is query param
        else if(location.search == "?type=friends"){
          $('#friends').show();
        }
        // Any other query param
        else {
          $('.default_name').show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: show your existing code.

Comment: @Justinas - Have updated my code ahead. Is that the best way of doing it or are there better ways? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.href; //get the url
var param = url.split('=')[1]; //split the url and get the parameter
$('#default').text(param) //set the text to url parameter
$('#default').attr('id',param); //now change the id from default to param
```

I wrote the required code using jquery! use different possible conditions(for eg: getting the id when id is family `$('#family')` and code accordingly.